# Mark an 2d-area on a 3dPlot (ListPlot3d)

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a list `{(IC,s,FK)}`, which I use to generate a 3d-plot with the help of the command `ListPlot3D`. `IC` and `s` go from `0` to `1`.

[image]

There is an area (lets say `0.11 < IC < 0.3, 0.1 < s < 0.4`) which is
specially important, because this is the physical range.
For some reason I want to plot the whole parameter space, but highlight (for example with a red rectangle)
this physical range. It would be great to frame the physical range with a red rectangle on the surface of the 3d-Plot. (In the end, this 2d-rectangle should look similar to these mesh lines, but it should frame the range, defined above).

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please include a self contained example (code) of what you're trying to do.

Comment: {(x,y,z)} isn't valid syntax

Comment: I took as guess as to what you want and posted below.  If it is not correct please use that as a reference to explain what you *do* want.

Comment: I wouldn't try to place a 2D unfilled rectangle parallel to the xy-plane to mark the domain of interest. It would be hard to make it both visible and easy to relate to the data. I think I'd go for superimposing a sub-plot of the same data with different coloring over the domain of interest. Wish I could work this out and post it, but I don't think I'll find the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With

```
 data = Table[{x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}], y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}], x^2 - y^2}, {300}];
```

Three possible methods are

1. using `ColorFunction`
2. using a combination of `Mesh`, `MeshFunctions` and `MeshShading`, (or, and better yet, just `Mesh` and `MeshShading` as in @Brett's answer)
3. produce two plots using different `RegionFunction` settings and combine them using `Show`.

**Using ColorFunction:**

```
 ListPlot3D[data, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, If[-.5 < x < .5 && -.3 < y < .1, Red, White]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   MaxPlotPoints -> 100, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

or with a different setting for the `ColorFunction`, say:

```
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, If[-.5 < x < .5 && -.3 < y < .1,
    ColorData["DeepSeaColors", (1 + x)/2], Directive[Opacity[.7], Hue[(1 + z)/2]]]]
```

[image]

**Using Mesh, MeshFunctions and MeshShading:**

```
 ListPlot3D[data,
  MeshFunctions -> {Boole[-.5 < #1 < .5 && -.2 < #2 < .75] &}, 
  Mesh -> {{1}},  MeshShading -> {White, Red}, 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic,  MaxPlotPoints -> 100, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

**Using RegionFunction and Show:**

```
lp1 = ListPlot3D[data,
    RegionFunction -> (! (-.5 < #1 < .5 && -.2 < #2 < .75) &),
    Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1,
    MaxPlotPoints -> 100, Lighting -> "Neutral",
    ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[.9], Hue[#1]] &), 
    Lighting -> "Neutral",   ImageSize -> 300];
lp2 = ListPlot3D[data,
    RegionFunction -> ((-.5 < #1 < .5 && -.2 < #2 < .75) &),
    Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1,
    MaxPlotPoints -> 100, Lighting -> "Neutral",
    ColorFunction -> (Red &), Lighting -> "Neutral",
    ImageSize -> 300];
    Panel@Row[{lp1, lp2, Show[{lp1, lp2}]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: lol -- when did *that* answer get there? +1

Comment: @Mr.W, same here - I should learn to reload the page every 30 secs or so :) Thank you for the vote.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: One last question. I chose solution number one, using 'ColorFunction'. Instead of the color white, I want use my originally blue color. I tried, but could not find the correct Colordata. Do you know it by accident? Would be great!

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the accept. You can try using, say, `Lighter@Lighter@Lighter@Blue` instead of `White` inside `If`. But ... I think it is easier to use the second approach to get the `Automatic` settings working nicely: just change `White` to `Automatic` and remove the `Lighting` option (or set it to `Automatic`).

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with the `Mesh` family of options.:

```
dat = Join @@ 
   Table[{x, y, Sin[10 x y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.05}, {y, 0, 1, 0.05}];

ListPlot3D[dat, Mesh -> {{0.11, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.4}}, MeshStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
       {Automatic, Directive[Red, Lighting -> "Neutral"], Automatic},   
       {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Since your example is in $x-y$ coordinates, we can use the default functions with specific positions, and use `MeshStyle -> None` to hide the lines (which we probably aren't interested in, in this case.)  Then we just have to construct the appropriate setting for `MeshShading`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Second attempt:

```
dat = Join @@ Table[{x, y, Sin[10 x y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.05}, {y, 0, 1, 0.05}];

ListPlot3D[
 dat,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (If[0.11 < # < 0.3 && 0.1 < #2 < 0.4, Red, Gray] &)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One method to clean up the fuzzy edge:

```
f = Interpolation[dat];

Plot3D[
 f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (If[0.11 < # < 0.3 && 0.1 < #2 < 0.4, Red, Gray] &),
 PlotPoints -> 100
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I seem to remember seeing a better one but I cannot recall it.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I am looking for a 2d-area on the surface of the 3d-plot. (Similar like these mesh-lines, but only in a certain area and with another color)

Comment: @Peter please see my updated answer and again give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is using `ListPlot3D` twice:

```
data = Join @@ 
   Table[{x, y, Sin[10 x y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.05}, {y, 0, 1, 0.05}];

g1 = ListPlot3D[data];
g2 = ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 0.11 < x < 0.3 && 0.1 < y < .4], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], PlotStyle -> None, 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 50]

Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]